# Exporting Jasper report in HTML Format stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" is not working (When no spaces)

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports

ITS WORKING FINE WITH PDF REPORTS BUT NOT WHEN I EXPORT JASPER CONTENT IN HTML REPORT

JASPER REPORT CODE----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" >
                    <reportElement key="" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="406" y="0" width="132" height="20" forecolor="#050505" uuid="7717f0db-9ebe-4fef-9465-370d96121dc2"/>
                    <box padding="2">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{days} != null?$F{days}+" day(s) ago" :"-"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
```

JAVA CODE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
                    HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
                        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out));
                        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
                        exporter.exportReport();
```

--- HTML REPORT EMAIL IS NOT STRECHING TO HEIGHT ---
[image: HTML REPORT HERE EMAIL IS NOT STRECHING TO HEIGHT AS NO SPACES]

--- PDF REPORT ITS WORKING FINE ---

[[image: SEE HERE ITS WORKING FINE WITH PDF2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.wrap.break.word](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.wrap.break.word) property to `true` either globally in `jasperreports.properties` or in the report.

Alternatively, you can set the [net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks) property (globally or in the report, but can also be set at element level).

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just want to add if anyone using this solution. Person should add the property manually there is no defined property in dropdown.